# What is a CleanUp badge?

Tags: discussion, badges

I am little confused about a certain badge. What exactly is a CleanUp badge?

- Does it entail Deleting your own questions?
- Does it entail Deleting your own answers?
- Does it entail Replacing your own answers?
- What is it that is being rolled back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CleanUp badge is award on the first time you rollback a post.

Reasons to rollback include:

- Another users edits were not comparable to your meaning
- You added additional information that was incorrect later
- Someone added tags to your question that didn't fit
- Someone tried to "clean up your spelling" and didn't realize your acronyms were correct

etc.

For deleting your own questions: see Disciplined and Peer Pressure

It would not entail replacing your own answers.

To give you a chance for the rollback, I'm going to edit your Q. Then I would like you to click the edited timestamp, and choose to rollback the post, by clicking rollback at the first edit. (source edit rollback)